# Was there any other Germanic person who gained an important position in The Byzantine Empire other than Emperor Tiberios III Apsimar?

Tags: byzantine-empire, germanic

I have read about Emperor Tiberios III, whose original name was Apsimar/Apsimaros. He was originally a droungarios in the Byzantine Fleet, and later deposed the Emperor Leontios. My question is: Were there any other Germanics beside Emperor Tiberios III who gained a significant position in the Byzantine Empire ?

Here's the link about him: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiberios_III

Comment: I guess it depends what you consider to be "important". The [Varangian Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varangian_Guard) come to mind as one possibility here.

Comment: does harald hadrada count,  are vikings considered germans?

Comment: Yes, Varangians count.

Comment: Er, still need a clarification - do you mean that Varangians count as Germanic people, or that being member of Varangian Guard is a significant enough position? Or both?

Answer (score 3):

Around 400 there was a massacre of the Gothic population in Constantinople. The Alans were spared from this because they looked different. Ardaburius, an Alan-Goth, was the Magister Militum of Theodosius. He outlasted Theodosius and became the most powerful person in the East, as did his son, Aspar. In the period from 420-476, these Alans controlled the Eastern Roman Empire. Their primary adversary was the Bonifacius, governor of Africa, and Galla Placidia, the regent in Rome. Aspar appears to have coordinated with the Vandals and Alans in their conquest of Africa. They were eventually able to turn Galla Placidia against Bonifacius. Their influence lasted until Aspar's son, Ardabur, was instigated in a conspiracy. This allowed Zeno to become emperor in 474 which began Isaurian rule. In 476 the Western Empire disappeared. Oh yea, Aspar also tutored Odoacer, king of Italy c. 476-493.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, it seems that you have a great amount of knowledge about the Byzantine Empire !

Comment: Those are the only ones that I know of. There were a lot of Frankish Mercenaries after the fourth crusade, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Harald Hardrada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Hardrada) started out as a member of the Varangian guard, and served in several campaigns in different parts of the Empire. Towards what would be the end of his career in Byzantium, he was awarded the titles *[Spatharokandidatos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatharokandidatos)* and *[Protospatharios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protospatharios)*. While these titles do not seem to have been much more than court titles, they do indicate that he was a known and important person. He also played a role in the fighting over who would succeed [Michael IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_IV_the_Paphlagonian) as Emperor.